# Convert string into json object

Tags: javascript, json

Im trying to convert a chunk of coordinates(lat/lng) into a json object with no luck at all. I want each line to be a pair.

I have a string that looks like this (+ 200 ish lines)

```
67.8574074243696,20.2120303794714
67.8570072289646,20.2137432009361
67.8562768208083,20.2153228755138
67.8558962489713,20.216419476191
```

I want to convert it into a json object that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "lat": xx.xxxxx,
        "lng": xx.xxxxxxx
    },
    {
        "lat": xx.xxxxx,
        "lng": xx.xxxxxxx
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: is the input string has lines separated with line breaks?

Comment: yep, i tried this wich does not really do the job.

            var json = [];
            var to = '67.8598076919889,20.2115077387607 67.8600208032472,20.2127390350463';
            var toSplit = to.split(" ");
            for (var i = 0; i < toSplit.length; i++) {
                json.push({"point":toSplit[i]});
            }

Comment: what is the line separator in your string?

Answer (score 0):

you can read line by line and pass to this function:

```
function parseCoordinates(coordinates){
  var tmpCoord = coordinates.split(',');
  return ({ 'lat': tmpCoord[0], 'lng': tmpCoord[1] });
}

var coords = array();
coords.push(parseCoordinates(lines1);
coords.push(parseCoordinates(lines2);
```

Or if the real chunk is for example in a variable wich name is chunk you can simply do something like that:

First separate chunk into lines:

```
var lines = chunk.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

then loop and call previous function.

```
var coords = array();
for(var i = 0; i< lines.length; i++){
  coords.push(parseCoordinates(lines[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my answer I assume your string is a csv.

You want to do something like:

```
var result = [];

var rows = csv.split('\n');

for(i in rows)
{

    var row = rows[i],
        values = row.split(',');

    result.push({
        lat: values[0],
        lng: values[1]
    });

}

json_result = JSON.stringify(result);
```

[Source](http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Where string is your json string.